# Different Results from To Char in Query

Tags: sql, oracle, report, to-char

Here is a part of my code :

```
WHERE DSTOCK_YYMM BETWEEN TO_CHAR(:P_PERIODE1,'YY')||'00' AND TO_CHAR(:P_PERIODE1,'YY')||LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR((TO_CHAR(:P_P‌​ERIODE1,'MM')-1),'00‌​')))
```

where :P_PERIODE1 is 1 December 2016 so in other words :

```
WHERE DSTOCK_YYMM BETWEEN '1600'
```

What I want to ask is in Report Developer, those queries gave different result... The right result came from the hardcoded one ('1600').
Can anyone help we with this? Thanks in advance

Anne

Comment: You are using between, is there another value to cap it? ie `between 1600 and <othervalue>`

Comment: What is the type of DSTOCK_YYMM ?

Comment: yes there is AND TO_CHAR(:P_PERIODE1,'YY')||LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR((TO_CHAR(:P_PERIODE1,'MM')-1),'00')))

Comment: @Aleksej DSTOCK_YYMM is varchar2

Comment: You have some issues in your code; please post the requirement you need to implement, with some sample data and needed result, so that people can understand your need and help you to build a safer code

Comment: Do you really like to compare with 2-digit year? Did you never heard [Y2k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) problem?

Comment: What happens on January? For today It would give 1799 -> For sure not correct.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for today it gives 1700?

Comment: @AnneFernandez You say that you get different results, but only give the result that you say is correct. What's the wrong result that you get?

Comment: @Boneist, yes you are right. But still not desired 1612.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit True, dat!

Answer (score 0):

This code gives me the same results... Maybe it will help you...

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YY')||'00' left_side, TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YY') || ltrim(to_char(to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')-1),'00')) right_side from dual;
```